# Processing Response in WP7 login Service calls

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, authentication

I need to call web services from my WP7 client application for user login pop up, and display the user the response whether the user is authenticated or not. My challenge is since all web service calls in WP7 are async, I am not sure how to pass the response message to the UI. The login method ends execution and I am trying to close the popup once the method execution is done. How do I keep my popup open till my async method call is done? I see some progress bar implemented in some of the WP7 apps. Will that solve my problem? Please share your thoughts and also point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: I didnt find a good forum that address all of my issues. There are solutions for login, web service call, progress bar etc... nothing to combine all the 3.

Comment: You should use a DispatcherTimer to keep tab on when the WebService call returns and then proceed to close the Popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code pattern may help:

```
void Authenticate()
{
    // start webservice here and 
    // show loading 
}

void Webservice_Callback()
{
    // process response

    Deployment.Current.Displatcher.BeginInvoke(AuthenticateCompleted);
}

void AuthenticateCompleted()
{
    // stop loading
    // close popup
}
```